# Chromebook photo access

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm looking for a way to access the files in "Downloads" on a Chromebook.

Currently, when a user takes a picture with the Camera app on Chrome OS, it stores a photo in the app. In that list of photos, you can choose to save the file to disk. Because the Chrome OS local storage options are limited, it seems like the options are to Google Drive or the local Downloads folder.

I'd like to be able to able to access these files through a developed extension (or other means if appropriate).

I found https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads, but it doesn't list random photos placed in the downloads folder since they were initiated from the browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're probably looking for https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

Comment: Oh man, not sure how I missed this! Thanks!

Comment: @JoshLee It looks like i can write a directory and potential select a file, but not programmatically browse through existing files in a directory and manage them (potentially delete) on my own. I noticed the ability to Android apps on Chrome OS, maybe that's what's needed to have a more native integration at the OS level.

Comment: Brandon: Note that there are also numerous Android apps that can access 'local files',  AND that, more and more Chromebook models now support running Android-apps.  e.g. see: https://www.theverge.com/2017/4/26/15432412/google-chromebook-android-apps-list

Comment: @Dave Funny you say that, b/c we have Android app in the store, I was surprised it actually worked when we installed it. Seems like Android support is just catching up. Thanks. That's definitely the path that seems like it makes the most sense.